# How can I filter records in a custom post type list in the admin based on the ACF field in the post that contains the current user?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have a custom post type called `Projects` that includes an ACF field named `team_members` which uses `User` as a field type and returns a User Array. I want to filter the post type listing so that the current logged-in user sees only records that contain their data in the `team_members` field.

I am trying to use this query, but it returns all the records:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');
function filter_posts_list($query)
{
    //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed
    global $pagenow, $typenow;  

    //$current_user uses the global
    global $current_user;

    //Shouldn't happen for the admin, but for any role with the edit_posts capability and only on the posts list page, that is edit.php
    if(!current_user_can('administrator') && current_user_can('edit_posts') && ('edit.php' == $pagenow) &&  $typenow == 'projects') { 

        $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
        
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'team_members',
                'value'   => $current_user_id,
                'compare' => "LIKE"
            ),
        ));
    
    }
}
```

Here is my custom field `team_members`:

[image: custom field]

And here is the example of a post from custom post type `Projects`:

[image]

How can I query only by the ACF field `team_members` that has the exact user ID as the current user in the post?

Comment: note that if this is a single post meta value that stores all the values then that will mean significant scope for false positives, e.g. searching for a user with `10` will also find users with `110` `2100` and `103`. This becomes trivial if they're stored as separate post meta with the same key though. Fundamentally using an ACF field to filter/search like this is going to be very bad for performance, this kind of filtering is what custom taxonomies are meant to be used for, not post meta

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads-up on the potential issues with using ACF fields for filtering. I get that it might lead to some false positives, and I'm all ears for better solutions. You mentioned custom taxonomies – sounds interesting! Any tips or resources on how to set those up for my situation? I'm a bit new to this, so any help is much appreciated!